# Rails / Devise - current_user returns wrong user object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am running a rails app (which uses Devise) in production on Heroku.  In it, `users` can post `reviews`.

**PROBLEM: A user posted a review and it hit the database with the wrong user_id.**

Here is the code that grabs the `user_id` when the `review` is created:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

I read [this github issue](https://github.com/baschtl/devise-token_authenticatable/issues/28), but was unsure if it applied to my case.  The issue talks about "skip persisting the session while you use token authentication," but I do not understand what that means.

The following is from my `config/initializers/devise.rb` file:

```
config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
```

Is calling `current_user` in the view the problem?  Should I only call it in the controller?

**UPDATE:** Below is code from `reviews_controller.rb`

```
def new
  @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
  @review = Review.new
end

def create
  @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
  @review = Review.new(review_params)

if @review.save
  redirect_to @vendor
else
  render 'new'
end 
end 
...

private
def review_params
  params.require(:review).permit(:title, :content, :rating, :flagged, :vendor_id, :user_id)
end
```

I appreciate any help.  I am new to this!

Comment: there's no problem in calling current_user in your view. And I have a strong belief that you're doing something wrong in that process to send it to the database (current_user returning wrong user_id doesn't seem likely). Put some logger.debug to check the user_id value in that process

Comment: Can you post your review controller?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far.  I have posted code from the reviews_controller.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using a hidden field to set the user ID? Without additional validation, this could allow malicious users to post reviews in someone else's name.

Comment: @Máté Solymosi - I appreciate that feedback. Would you add user_id to the form's params in the create method before sending review_params to Review.new?

Comment: If the `User` model `has_many :reviews`, then you can write this instead: `@review = current_user.reviews.build`. Then remove `user_id` from the list of permitted `review_params`, and delete the hidden field. Of course if `current_user` is not the right user, this does not solve that problem. I mentioned it just as a side note.